# Data Sync between Mongodb Primary Secondary does not match

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Mon-Delay Sync delay between Primary and Secondary in Mongodb

after `object.save()`

If you do a find, the object you just saved is not retrieved.

In my opinion, before the object created in the `Primary` is replicated to the `Secondary`, it seems to ask for Find to confirm that there is no data in the `Secondary`.
Can you compensate for this?

Before that, is my hypothesis correct? Does Mongodb not behave like a waiting process when there is data in Sycn through opLog?

What are the causes and solutions?

I changed `readPreferred` from `secondaryPreferred` to `primaryPreferred` and it worked fine.

The problem occurs in `secondaryPreferred`.

```
object.save(function ( err, saved ) {
    callback(err, saved);
});
```

I've confirmed that it may be due to asynchronous problem, but save works in the form of a callback.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-write-concern/

It was a mistake to expect a performance improvement as a `Secondary`. We decided to use `Secondary` only when we need to use data backup or aggregate query.
My conclusion is that it is correct to use only `Primary`.